# difference between two array using php

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I am Having Two array like the following ,

```
$a =array(1,2,3,4);
$b =array(1,2,5,6);
```

here is mycode

```
$c=array_diff($a,$b);
$c=array(3,4,5,6);
```

but i want it like the following

```
$c=array(3,4);
```

**Note:**

i want `$a` array value which is not present in `$b` array.

Comment: `array_diff()` should do exactly what you want. It works for me - http://codepad.viper-7.com/tMTzzG

Comment: remove $c=array(3,4,5,6);. your code already produces the results you need. In my tests the value of $c is array(3, 4)

Comment: `$c=array_diff($b,$a);`

Comment: @M1K1O: No. That would return all elements in `$b` that are not present in `$a`.

Comment: `Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.` Should behave exactly as you expect it to behave. Are you sure your code is correct? Post the 1-on-1 copied code of your test otherwise.

Comment: @SivaG Your code is correct. You are rewriting the new value. Remove `$c=array(3,4,5,6);`

Comment: thank you all it is correct only .............sorry some confusion i made an inquiry here.......... now it is ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4);
$array2 = array(1,2,5,6);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

read this PHp.NET for [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)
and also refer this [FIDDLE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9MMHjQ)

Answer (score 3):

i know `array_diff` is the best way but dianuj's answer wasnt quite kosher and a comment may not have been communicated well enough.

```
<?php

$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(1,2,5,6);

foreach($a as $k => $v)
{
    if (in_array($v, $b))
        unset($a[$k]);
}

var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new array without maintaining the old keys, try this

```
$c = array_values(array_diff($a, $b));
```

Example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/bVaJG5

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
// get differences that in ary_1 but not in ary_2
foreach ( $ary_1 as $v1 ) {
    $flag = 0;
    foreach ( $ary_2 as $v2 ) {
        $flag |= ( $v1 == $v2 );
        if ( $flag ) break;
    }
    if ( !$flag ) array_push( $diff, $v1 );
}
```

where :

```
$ary_1 = $a & $ary_2 = $b
```